# How to set double precision in MathNet.Symbolics Evaluate function?

Tags: c#, math.net, mathnet-numerics, mathdotnet-symbolics

I have a `Dictionary<string, double> values` and values precision is important for me. I have a string Formula that Infix can Parse. I wonder how to do something like this:

```
var expr = Infix.ParseOrThrow(m.Formula);
var result = Evaluate.Evaluate<double>(values, expr);
```

to get a result with double precision?

Comment: @Alex: if these tags have the same meaning, please put effort into merging them, rather than adding redundant tags to questions. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369717/tags-mathdotnet-and-mathnet-seem-to-be-redundant Thanks!

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I'm interested in the tag. So I tried to add synonyms. It is said that synonyms have allready been proposed. But one still have to search for three different tags to find all `mathnet` questions.

Comment: @Alex: please read here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate operates on a custom `FloatingPoint` type which can represent various double-precision floating-point values (mostly real or complex numbers, in theory also vectors or matrices). You can cast a `double` to a `FloatingPoint`, and use `RealValue` to get a double back from a `FloatingPoint`.

Example:

```
var variables = new Dictionary<string,FloatingPoint>
   {{ "a", 2.0 },
    { "b", 3.0 }};

var expr = Infix.ParseOrThrow("2/3*a");
double result = Evaluate.Evaluate(variables, expr).RealValue;
```